# Cloud Vision API poorly recognizes 7-segment numbers

Tags: google-vision

#### The simplest example of what I'm trying to recognize:

[image: The simplest example of what I'm trying to recognize]

I use `DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION`, but in the answer I get the hieroglyphics.

If I use `Eng` in the `ImageContext` parameter for the `addAllLanguageHints` method, then I have 111 in result. Better, but still bad.

Is there any way to indicate that the numbers are recognised or somehow improve the results?

Also, how is the `setRepeatedField` option in `ImageContext` is used? I could not find any examples of its use.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same problem.

I found some pre-processing code here: https://github.com/arturaugusto/display_ocr

But it does not seem to help much when using Google Cloud Vision (e.g. when you take the screenshot of the "22" from that repo and send it to the Vision API it is not recognised correctly).

I have been playing around with various OpenCV preprocessing techniques - but not much luck.

Answer (score 2):

Even if it doesn't work out of the box ... you'd need is to classify images using custom labels, when the default labels won't suffice. [Cloud Auto ML Vision](https://cloud.google.com/automl/) (select Vision from that blue drop-down menu) let's you train custom models, which can be used to recognize that font. And since the possible amount of shapes is quite limited with that 7-segment display, it shouldn't be too difficult to train it. If you'd get a calculator with a better display, it might also work better. The LCD above looks a little cheap, with those huge spaces and cut-off endings - but nevertheless, one can train it to read that.